# How to show / set a pipeline Opportunity "marked as important" on the record page?

Tags: opportunity

With SFDC recently making Opportunity Pipelines free to Enterprise Edition customers, I went ahead and explored it. From the Pipelines Inspection button, you can see your Opportunities and mark them as important.

- Can you see on a record page whether the Opportunity is important?
- Can you mark the opportunity as important on a record page?
- Can you report or query on important opportunities?

The field in the schema is called `Opportunity.IsPriorityRecord`

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*All as of V57.0*

**Can you see on a record page whether the Opportunity is important?**

Nope, per the [Pipeline Inspection doc](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.pipeline_inspection_guidelines.htm&type=5).

> You can see and mark opportunities as important in Pipeline Inspection only.

- You can't create a formula field to `IsPriorityRecord`.
- It is not available in the list of fields for a page layout
- You can't write a trigger on Opportunity that detects changes in `IsPriorityRecord` that you could copy to a custom field because when you (un)mark an Opportunity as important, there is no trigger invoked.

**Can you mark the opportunity as important on a record page?**

Nope - same as above.

- The schema field is marked as `updateable false`
- There's no OOTB quick action to mark the Opportunity as important

**Can you report or query on important opportunities?**

- SOQL queries do work. Although the doc states  `Important opportunities are visible only to the user who marked them and can’t be shared with other users.`, SOQL can find this field's value regardless of running user/opportunity owner
- The field (whose label = `Important`) is not available in the OOTB Opportunities report type
- The field is not available for use in Custom Report Types

*If others know the history behind this feature, please comment. It has the "taste and smell" of an acquisition.*